# Can I limit Apache directives by file owner/permission?

Tags: apache-2.2, security

The aim here is a security catch-all to disallow php execution of files created by the apache user (i.e. uploaded to a php script). Also we'd change the .html/.htm/.xhtml etc to text/plain to help protect against JS based attacks on other users.

Something like:

```
<FileOwnerMatch apache>
    #Disable PHP execution
    #change mime types
</FileOwnerMatch>
```

Can it be done?

NB We do check file extensions on uploads, but we'd like somethng akin to the above for added peace of mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that Apache is only allowed to write into specific directories  and disallow *all* execution for this directories (both CGI and PHP) with a `<directory>` statement.

Deactivating PHP can be done with a statement

```
php_flag engine off
```

in the `<directory>` part of your Apache configuration.

Comment: Yes, we already do something equivalent. But as mentioned in the original post this is a catch all safety net. Just in case there are 777 directories somewhere that we have missed, or that get created in the future.